# PS-Remoting / Winrm allow only outbound connections

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

I have a lot of workstations in a network and server.

All the clients trust this server and it's used to execute commands on the workstations (maintainance, etc). These tasks are executed from the server. However, I also have to add all the clients to the `TrustedHosts` on the server or it won't connect. (It's not in a domain and I'm using http).

Which means that, in theory, a client could connect to a server and gain access (if knowing/guessing the credentials), which is not desirable in that case. I did not enable `AllowUnencryted` on the server, which should block incoming connections, but I'm not sure if that is enough.

Might that be enough to protect the server or is there something like `TrustedClients`?

Comment: `winrm/Config/Client/TrustedHosts`? Or is that what you're currently configuring?  Have a look at `winrm/config/winrs/AllowRemoteShellAccess`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes I have to add the remote machines to `winrm/Config/Client/TrustedHosts` in order to connect to them. Ah so `winrm/config/winrs/AllowRemoteShellAccess = false` will prevent any of the trusted hosts from connecting to the machine while still enabling me to execute stuff on remote machines from there?

Comment: I just glanced at the winrm config, but it's worth testing (I do not have an environment available atm to test myself)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 me neither, but it seems to be what I was looking for, Thanks a lot!